# Counting String Values in Pivot Across Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to use Pandas to pivot a table into multiple columns, and get the count of their values.

In this example table:

| LOCATION | ADDRESS | PARKING TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA0001 | 123 MAIN | LARGE LOT |
| AAA0001 | 123 MAIN | SMALL LOT |
| AAA0002 | 456 TOWN | LARGE LOT |
| AAA0003 | 789 AVE | MEDIUM LOT |
| AAA0003 | 789 AVE | MEDIUM LOT |

How do I pivot out this table to show total counts of each string within "Parking Type"? Maybe my mistake is calling this a "pivot?"

Desired output:

| LOCATION | ADDRESS | SMALL LOT | MEDIUM LOT | LARGE LOT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA0001 | 123 MAIN | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| AAA0002 | 456 TOWN | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| AAA0003 | 789 AVE | 0 | 2 | 0 |

Currently, I have a pivot going, but it is only counting the values of the first column, and leaving everything else as 0s. Any guidance would be amazing.

Current Code:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["LOCATION"], columns=['PARKING TYPE'], aggfunc=len)
pivot = pivot.reset_index()
pivot.columns = pivot.columns.to_series().apply(lambda x: "".join(x))
```

Comment: I suspect that the [`get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) function does this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `pd.crosstab`:

```
out = (pd.crosstab(index=[df['LOCATION'], df['ADDRESS']], columns=df['PARKING TYPE'])
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(columns=[None]))
```

or you could use `pivot_table` (but you have to pass "ADDRESS" into the index as well):

```
out = (pd.pivot_table(df, index=['LOCATION','ADDRESS'], columns=['PARKING TYPE'], values='ADDRESS', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(columns=[None]))
```

Output:

```
  LOCATION   ADDRESS  LARGE LOT  MEDIUM LOT  SMALL LOT
0  AAA0001  123 MAIN          1           0          1
1  AAA0002  456 TOWN          1           0          0
2  AAA0003   789 AVE          0           2          0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `get_dummies()` and then a grouped `sum` to get a row per your groups:

```
>>> pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['PARKING TYPE']).groupby(['LOCATION','ADDRESS'],as_index=False).sum()

  LOCATION   ADDRESS  PARKING TYPE_LARGE LOT  PARKING TYPE_MEDIUM LOT  PARKING TYPE_SMALL LOT
0  AAA0001  123 MAIN                       1                        0                       1
1  AAA0002  456 TOWN                       1                        0                       0
2  AAA0003   789 AVE                       0                        2                       0
```